# Conditional image resizing with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave

I need to create different versions of uploaded image conditionally. I know Carrierwave supports this feature. But my requirements are a bit tricky.

For each uploaded image I need to create 2 versions and need to scale the original image based on conditions.

Below code will give you better idea what I am trying to do:

```
version :leftright, :if => :image?  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [667*2, 778*2] ,:if => :is_retina_resolution?
  process :resize_to_fill => [667, 778]  ,:if => !:is_retina_resolution?
end

version :updown, :if => :image?  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [1024*2, 487*2] ,:if => :is_retina_resolution?
  process :resize_to_fill => [1024, 487]  ,:if => !:is_retina_resolution?
end

#resize the original image
process :resize_to_fill => [1024*2, 768*2] ,:if => :is_retina_resolution?
process :resize_to_fill => [1024, 768]  ,:if => !:is_retina_resolution?

def is_retina_resolution?(new_file)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(new_file.file)
  true if image[:height] >= 1536 and image[:width] >= 2048
end
```

Apparently this is not working. Carrierwave throws this error:

`Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory - #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xe41d508>`

And I tried another variation:

```
version :leftright, :if => :image?  do
  if :is_retina_resolution?
    process :resize_to_fill => [667*2, 778*2]
  else
    process :resize_to_fill => [667, 778]
  end
end

version :updown, :if => :image?  do
  if :is_retina_resolution?
    process :resize_to_fill => [1024*2, 487*2]
  else
    process :resize_to_fill => [1024, 487]
  end
end

def is_retina_resolution?(new_file)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(new_file)
  true if image[:height] >= 1536 and image[:width] >= 2048
end
```

This doesn't throw any error. But it always generates the image in `retina size` (1st condition)

So I tried one more variation:

```
version :leftright, :if => :image? && :is_retina_resolution  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [667*2, 778*2] 
end

version :leftright, :if => :image? && !:is_retina_resolution  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [667, 778] 
end

version :updown, :if => :image? && :is_retina_resolution  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [1024*2, 487*2]    
end

version :updown, :if => :image? && !:is_retina_resolution  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [1024, 487] 
end
```

This doesnt throw any error and also not created any version.

Can someone help me out?

**Update:**

Based on the suggestion by @DMKE, I made this changes, now it works fine

```
version :leftright, :if => :image?  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [667*2, 778*2] ,:if => :is_retina_resolution?
  process :resize_to_fill => [667, 778]  ,:if => :is_not_retina_resolution?
end

version :updown, :if => :image?  do
  process :resize_to_fill => [1024*2, 487*2] ,:if => :is_retina_resolution?
  process :resize_to_fill => [1024, 487]  ,:if => :is_not_retina_resolution?    
end

#resize the original image
process :resize_to_fill => [1024*2, 768*2] ,:if => :image_and_retina?
process :resize_to_fill => [1024, 768]  ,:if => :image_and_not_retina?
process :if => :not_image?

def image_and_retina?(img)
  is_img = image? img
  return false unless is_img
  return is_retina_resolution?(img)
end

def image_and_not_retina?(img)
  is_img = image? img
  return false unless is_img
  return !is_retina_resolution?(img)
end

# returns true if image file
def image?(new_file)
  self.file.content_type.include? 'image'
end

def not_image?(new_file)
  !self.file.content_type.include? 'image'
end

def is_retina_resolution?(new_file)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.file.file)
  true if image[:height] >= 1536 and image[:width] >= 2048
end

def is_not_retina_resolution?(new_file)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.file.file)
  true if image[:height] < 1536 and image[:width] < 2048
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although not a syntax error, this code has a semantical flaw:

```rb
version :updown, :if => :image? && !:is_retina_resolution  do
  # ...
end
```

Here, `:image? && !:is_retina_resolution` **always** evaluates to false (try `!:foo` in an IRb terminal), thus the `:updown` version is *never* created. The same explanation goes for `process foo: [sx,sy], if: !:bar?`

Since CarrierWave does not support an `:unless` option (as far as I can tell), the only way to achieve your goal are some method definitions in your `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` subclass:

```rb
process resize_to_fill: [667*2, 778*2], if: :image_and_retina?
process resize_to_fill: [667, 778],     if: :image_and_not_retina?

def image_and_retina?(img)
  image?(img) && is_retina_resolution(img)
end

def image_and_not_retina?(img)
  image?(img) && !is_retina_resolution(img)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @DMKE, based on your suggestion, i have made some changes, and it works fine now.

Comment: One is glad to be of service.