# Minimagick undefined method `width='

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, minimagick

I want to use specific version of image by their width and height. So I followed [How-to:-Get-image-dimensions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions) this wiki, but got `undefined method "width="`.
My ***uploader*** looks like,

```
class S3uploaderUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process :store_dimensions


  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  version :detail do
    process :quality => 90
    process :store_dimensions
  end


  version :mainVertical do
    process :quality => 80
    process :store_dimensions
    process :resize_to_fit => [240, 180]
  end

  version :mainHorizontal do
    process :quality => 80
    process :store_dimensions
    process :resize_to_fit => [240, 320]
  end

  private

  def store_dimensions
    if file && model
      model.width, model.height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an idea from this post. [conditional-image-resizing-with-carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651900/conditional-image-resizing-with-carrierwave). It works well.

And I changed my code like this.

```
class S3uploaderUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

    version :detail do
      process :quality => 90
    end
    version :main, :if => :image?  do
        process :quality => 90
        process :resize_to_fit => [240, 180] ,:if => :horizontal?
        process :resize_to_fit => [240, 320]  ,:if => :vertical?
    end

  def image?(new_file)
      self.file.content_type.include? 'image'
  end

  def horizontal?(new_file)
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.file.file)
    true if image[:height] < image[:width]
  end

  def vertical?(new_file)
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.file.file)
    true if image[:height] > image[:width]
  end
end
```